# R - substituting promise expression from globalenv

Tags: r, promise, substitution

```
>#R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10) -- "Sock it to Me"
> library(pryr)
> f1 <- function() { cat("hi1\n"); 1 }
> f2 <- function() { cat("hi2\n"); 2 }
```

This is what I would like to have but with `e` = `globalenv`:

```
> e <- new.env()
> delayedAssign("x", f1(), assign.env = e)
> substitute(x, e)
f1()
```

If I try `substitute` it does not work (according to doc, there is no `substitute` in `globalenv`):

```
> delayedAssign("x", f1(), assign.env = globalenv())
> substitute(x, globalenv())
x
```

`subs` from `pryr` doesn not work either because it evaluates the promise:

```
> subs(x, globalenv())
hi1
[1] 1
```

in fact it evaluates all promises, because it converts `globalenv` to a list:

```
> delayedAssign("x", f1(), assign.env = globalenv())
> delayedAssign("y", f2(), assign.env = globalenv())
> subs(x, globalenv())
hi1
hi2
[1] 1
>
```

To sum up: Is it possible to have something like `substitute` that works with promises in all environments including `globalenv`?

**UPDATE**

I could not figure out how to do this within R, so I wrote (more precisely lifted from the R code) the following C func

```
SEXP get_no_eval(SEXP symbol, SEXP envir) {
  SEXP t;

  if (!Rf_isString(symbol) || Rf_length(symbol)!=1) 
    Rf_error("symbol is not a string");

  if (!Rf_isEnvironment(envir)) 
    Rf_error("envir is not an environment");

  if (envir==R_NilValue) 
    Rf_error("envir is NULL");

  t = Rf_findVar(Rf_install(CHAR(STRING_ELT(symbol, 0))), envir);
  if (t != R_UnboundValue) {
    if (TYPEOF(t) == PROMSXP) {
      do {
        t = PREXPR(t);
      } while(TYPEOF(t) == PROMSXP);
      if (NAMED(t) < 2) SET_NAMED(t, 2);
      return t;
    }
    else if (TYPEOF(t) == DOTSXP)
      Rf_error("'...' used in an incorrect context");
    return t;
  }

  Rf_error("symbol not found");
  return R_NilValue;
}
```

Now, continuing my example from above I can do:

```
> delayedAssign("x", f1(), assign.env = globalenv())
> get_no_eval("x", globalenv())
f1()
```

Not exactly `substitute` but works for what I needed.

Comment: Your question would be improved with an example and by removing the editorial comments.

Comment: Alright. How is it now?

Comment: I often hack around this with `quote`/`expression` and `eval`. And for the function case, at least, you can use `call` instead of `delayedAssign; substitute`.

Comment: Try the lazyeval package

Comment: Not sure how to get the expression out. Here is what I have

Comment: library(lazyeval)
f1<-function () { cat("hi1\n"); 1 }
delayedAssign("x", a+b, assign.env=globalenv())
lazy(x, globalenv())$expr

Comment: Sorry. I give up with this... What I meant is that I do not know how to get the expression out: lazy(...)$expr returns <promise: ....>, but how do I get the expression out? Like in my example above with e!=globalenv().